# Null pointer exception error : database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Im having troubles with displaying one Event information from my database. After clicking on my Event from event list in DayPlan.java it should show me some informations about this event but it simply crashes whole application with error : Nullpointer exception :( 
I used thiscodeasa base:  [Database example](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-example)

error is somewhere in OnPostExecute from ViewEvent, could anyone please help me?

my database connector:

```
    package com.examples.android.calendar;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class DatabaseConnector {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "watchaday";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

       public void open() throws SQLException 
       {
          //open database in reading/writing mode
          database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       } 

       public void close() 
       {
          if (database != null)
             database.close();
       }       

       public void insertContact(String date, String hour_from, String hour_to, String event, String colour) 
               {
                  ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
                  newCon.put("date", date);
                  newCon.put("hour_from", hour_from);
                  newCon.put("hour_to", hour_to);
                  newCon.put("event", event);
                  newCon.put("colour", colour);


                  open();
                  database.insert("calendar_events", null, newCon);
                  close();
               }


               public void updateContact(long id, String date, String hour_from, String hour_to, String event, String colour) 
               {
                  ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
;
                  editCon.put("date", date);
                  editCon.put("hour_from", hour_from);
                  editCon.put("hour_to", hour_to);
                  editCon.put("event", event);
                  editCon.put("colour", colour);

                  open();
                  database.update("calendar_events", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }


               public Cursor getAllContacts() 
               {
                  return database.query("calendar_events", new String[] {"_id", "event"}, 
                     null, null, null, null, "date");
               }

               public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
               {
                  return database.query("calendar_events", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
               }

               public void deleteContact(long id) 
               {
                  open(); 
                  database.delete("calendar_events", "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }
}
```

my database Helper:

```
 package com.examples.android.calendar;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE calendar_events (_id integer primary key autoincrement,date, hour_from, hour_to, event, colour);";                 
        db.execSQL(createQuery);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

my Event List code :

```
 package com.examples.android.calendar;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class DayPlan extends ListActivity {

     public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
     private ListView conListView;
     private CursorAdapter conAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        conListView=getListView();
        conListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewConListener);

        // map each name to a TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { "event" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.countryTextView };
        conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(DayPlan.this, R.layout.day_plan, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
       super.onResume();  
       new GetContacts().execute((Object[]) null);
     } 


    @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
       Cursor cursor = conAdapter.getCursor();

       if (cursor != null) 
          cursor.deactivate();

       conAdapter.changeCursor(null);
       super.onStop();
    }    


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
    {
       DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(DayPlan.this);

       @Override
       protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
       {
          dbConnector.open();
          return dbConnector.getAllContacts(); 
       } 

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
       {
          conAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
          dbConnector.close();
       } 
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.dayplan_menu, menu);
       return true;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
       Intent addContact = new Intent(DayPlan.this, AddEvent.class);
       startActivity(addContact);
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    OnItemClickListener viewConListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
       {         
          Intent viewCon = new Intent(DayPlan.this, ViewEvent.class);
          viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
          startActivity(viewCon);
       }
    };    

}
```

my View event code which crashes application in OnPostExecute part:

ViewEvent.java :

```
public class ViewEvent extends Activity {

   private long rowID;
   private TextView dateTv;
   private TextView hourfromTv;
   private TextView hourtoTv; 
   private TextView eventTv;
   private TextView colourTv; 

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_event);

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(DayPlan.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       dateTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
       hourfromTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour_fromText);
       hourtoTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour_toText);
       eventTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventText);
       colourTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colourText);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewEvent.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {

         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
       int dateindex = result.getColumnIndex("date");
         int hourfromIndex = result.getColumnIndex("hour_from");
         int hourtoIndex = result.getColumnIndex("hour_to");
         int eventIndex = result.getColumnIndex("event");
         int colourIndex = result.getColumnIndex("colour");

         dateTv.setText(result.getString(dateindex));
         hourfromTv.setText(result.getString(hourfromIndex));
         hourtoTv.setText(result.getString(hourtoIndex));
         eventTv.setText(result.getString(eventIndex));
         colourTv.setText(result.getString(colourIndex));

         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_event_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEvent.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(DayPlan.ROW_ID, rowID);

            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }

   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewEvent.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewEvent.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
   }
}
```

Error :

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): java.lang.NullPointerException

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.examples.android.calendar.ViewEvent$LoadContacts.onPostExecute(ViewEvent.java:76)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.examples.android.calendar.ViewEvent$LoadContacts.onPostExecute(ViewEvent.java:1)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

12-30 17:52:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 17:52:31.463: I/Process(1173): Sending signal. PID: 1173 SIG: 9
12-30 17:52:32.305: E/Trace(1191): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: Adding a crash log would probably get you more useful replies

Comment: If you were to post the stack trace from the debugger, we'd know exactly where the error was occurring and could better help you resolve the issue.

Comment: sorry, Ive already edited postwith error.

Comment: A nullpointer is pretty much the easiest to fix error in any language: there is just some object you're using which isn't initiated or some other method returns null which are not expecting.
Debug your code and figure out what is null.

Comment: Which line is #76 in `ViewEvent.java`?

Comment: dateTv.setText(result.getString(dateindex));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the error was due to wrong resource Id.Still read below

result.moveToFirst() returns true if there is at least one record returned in your query.
Proper way of using it:

```
if(result.moveToFirst()){

       int dateindex = result.getColumnIndex("date");
         int hourfromIndex = result.getColumnIndex("hour_from");
         int hourtoIndex = result.getColumnIndex("hour_to");
         int eventIndex = result.getColumnIndex("event");
         int colourIndex = result.getColumnIndex("colour");

         dateTv.setText(result.getString(dateindex));
         hourfromTv.setText(result.getString(hourfromIndex));
         hourtoTv.setText(result.getString(hourtoIndex));
         eventTv.setText(result.getString(eventIndex));
         colourTv.setText(result.getString(colourIndex));

}
```

Comment: Your dateTv seems to be null. Check in your layout if id is 'date' or something else.

Comment: THANK YOU !  i had DATA instead of DATE. THANK YOU !